# Speed up simple image preprocessing function

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, optimization, keras

I created this simple function based on a scikit-image [function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_equalize.html):

```
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np

def hist_contr_func(image):
    '''Function from skimage that corrects the histogram to enhance contrast - "Adaptive equalization" '''
    # Line below is needed, because equalize_adapthist works in pixel value range (0,1)
    image = image / 255.

    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    # Line below is required, because equalize_adapthist works on arrays with shape (h,w)
    image = np.resize(image, (h,w))
    img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(image, clip_limit=0.03)

    # I back-resize, because keras works with arrays with shape (h,w,channels)
    img_adapteq = np.resize(img_adapteq, (h,w,1))

    return img_adapteq
```

**How can I speed up the function?** I guess the bottleneck is in `exposure.equalize_adapthist`, but improvements to the resizing calculations are also appreciated

More, but not essential info: I am using the function for preprocessing images in keras:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.15,
    preprocessing_function=hist_contr_func)
```

Without `preprocessing_function=hist_contr_func` my keras script runs 5 times faster. I would also appreciate recommendations of other contrast-enhancing, histogram correcting packages that work faster. Thanks!

Comment: The question now is: why do you need histogram equalization?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think my code is as intended: first I need to get my grey image into shape (h,w), then perform the histogram equalization, and then bring the result back to shape (h,w,1) (look at my code comments). I do the histogram equalization, because I classify images with very simple features (1 dot or 2 dots) and I want to increase the contrast in the images

Comment: Does the detection actually work better with histogram equalization compared to a simple linear contrast stretch? I wouldn’t expect so, especially if all you’re doing is detecting dots.